# Problem with use WebSocket transport on SignalR ASP.NET WebForms app with Azure SignalR with custom domain

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, signalr, azure-custom-domain

I have a problem with use custom domain on SignalR Azure Service with my ASP.NET WebForms app containing SignalR hub.

I configured custom domain at SignalR Azure Service as in the picture

[Azure SingalR Service custom domain configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrh3F.jpg)

When i use connection string like this:

```
"Endpoint=https://example_endpoint;AccessKey=example_accesskey;Version=1.0;"
```

everything works perfectly and I get WebSocket transport.

But when i trying to use custom domain in connecton string like this:

```
"Endpoint=https://example_endpoint;AccessKey=example_accesskey;ClientEndpoint=custom_domaint_endpoint;Version=1.0;"
```

I get "HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available" error and my transport is switching go SSE.

[Console SignalR client logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsHdO.jpg)

**What should I do on server or client side to have SignalR communication with custom domain and WebSockets transport?**